# "This" is returning [object Window], not the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I have this simple code for debugging (there's more, but this is the stripped version):

```
function calc(container) {
    console.log(container);
    return 100;
};

$(".replace").text(calc(this));
```

The console is just returning the `window`, not the element. Why is this? Is there something that prevents jQuery/JavaScript from returning the element?

Comment: Yes, `this` is `window` in that scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `calc` method is not invoked within the element's context, you need to use something like

```
$(".replace").text(function(){
    return calc(this)
});
```

in this case the `calc` method is invoked within a callback method where `this` refers to the current element.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KGx2q/)

Comment: This replaces the text with `function (){ percentCalc(this); }` and doesn't log anything because the function doesn't run.

Comment: Yeah, the accepted answer works for me, but not this one. Strange.

Comment: @Ian then the question what are you trying to do with the parameter `container`? are you trying to call any jquery method on it?

Comment: OK, turns out this was because I was using the Scratchpad. It does work when I am not using the scratchpad, and it works better for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

`this` here refers to the window object

```
$(".replace").text(calc(this));
```

you should use

```
$(".replace").text(function(){
    return calc(this); // here this refers to the current element with class replace
});
```

Read [this keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: lol so weird I literally JUST read that doc page today at lunch.

Comment: This replaces the text with function (){ percentCalc(this); } and doesn't log anything because the function doesn't run.

Answer (score 2):

In the global context, `this` *is* `window`.

```
> this === window
true
```

What you want is probably something like this:

```
var $replace = $(".replace");
$replace.text(calc($replace));
```

Comment: Yes I understand; my comment was for the people playing along at home :)

Answer (score 1):

Just another option, since you are looking for the element just use your function reference itself as the argument of [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text).

```
function calc() {
    console.log(this);
    return 100;
};

$(".replace").text(calc);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right.

Because when you call that function the current scope is window.

If you want to use the element, use function parameter instead.

Refer [jQuery set text](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp)

Comment: The value of *this* has nothing to do with scope, it is always resolved in the current execution context (and is always set on entering an execution context).